# Drawing and Shading Circle Sections

Tags: python

So, I have to do some graphics/visualization work, which is turning out to be a nightmare as I have 0 experience in this area.

In short, I have a series of concentric circles (b, c, d) with radii of 1, 2, 3, and perpendicular lines, (e, f) that pass through the origin (-x - y = 0 and -x + y = 0).  Below is a GeoGebra visualization:

[image: concentric circles centered on origin with x-y axes and lines at x=y and x=-y]

I also have an array of 12 greyscale pixel values.  Each value in this array corresponds to the colour a section of the image is to be shaded (3 circles, each with 4 sections).  Below is a sample image where I shaded an area in pink for clarity.

[image]

I have been able to create pie slices that I can shade, which works for sections in circle b, but not the other two.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

x_center = 400 // 2
y_center = 400 //2

img = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 400), 'white')

idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

idraw.pieslice([x_center-100, x_center-100, 
               y_center + 106, y_center + 106], 225, 315, fill='blue')
```

[image]

And have gotten close with a chord, but I would need an arc'd bottom, not a straight line

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

x_center = 400 // 2
y_center = 400 //2

im = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 400), 'white')

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.chord([x_center-100, x_center-100, 
           y_center + 106, y_center + 106], 225, 315, fill='blue')
```

[image]

Now, the end goal is to take the final product and save it as a png or jpeg.  This is because each image reflects a timeslice and I want to smush them all together into a video.  However, I am 100% open to using whatever tool works best, be it PIL, matplotlib, etc. (I simply have 0 experience with this type of stuff, so my decision to use PIL/PILLOW may not be the smartest).

Any insights into this matter would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that you intend for the circle to be centered at the coordinates you named as `x_center` and `y_center`, you need to add and subtract the same value for the bounding boxes, vs. using `[x_center-100, x_center-100, 
           y_center+106, y_center+106]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a sequence of sectors from the largest first down to the smallest. Successively smaller circle sectors will be drawn on top of previous ones, giving the region shapes you're looking for. Using your code calling `idraw.pieslice`, for example,

```
idraw.pieslice([x_center-100, x_center-100, 
           y_center+100, y_center+100], 225, 315, fill='blue')
idraw.pieslice([x_center-80, x_center-80, 
           y_center+80, y_center+80], 225, 315, fill='red')
```

Comment: I was just starting to write the same thing. As long as the regions are opaque, this should work like a charm.  Cheers!

Comment: Of course you can draw over stuff... that is a much better solution than what I had come up with.  I have to draw 5000 of these things, so this solution will save me a lot of time. Thanks!

Comment: If you're repeatedly drawing the same pattern, it would make more sense to generate the pattern just once and paste repeatedly. Generate the pattern with transparency (RGBA). Pasting in a RGBA rectangle is faster than drawing two circle wedges.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so, after not sleeping for almost 2 days, I found a solution for anyone who happens to also have this problem, now or in the future.

In short, I found all of the coordinates that fall within each section, then built a bitmap image.  It is not particularly fast, but it works.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def inside_circle(radius, x_center, y_center):
    """
    Determines all points that fall within a circle

    Returns a set of tuples with each tuple being an x-y coordinate 
    inside the circle

    """

    valid = set()

    for x in xrange(0, 601):
        for y in xrange(0, 601):
            if ((x - x_center)*(x- x_center)) + \
               ((y - y_center)*(y - y_center)) <= radius*radius:
                valid.add((x, y))

    return valid

def above_line(all_points, p1, p2):
    """
    Determines if each point is above the line defined by p1 and p2

    Returns a set of tuples with each tuple being an x-y coordinate 
    above line

    """

    valid = set()

    for point in all_points:
        p = np.array([point])
        is_above = np.cross(p-p1, p2-p1) < 0

        if is_above:
            valid.add(tuple(point))

    return valid

# Find all points in each circle
circle_1 = inside_circle(radius=100, x_center=300, y_center=300)
circle_2 = inside_circle(radius=200, x_center=300, y_center=300)
circle_3 = inside_circle(radius=300, x_center=300, y_center=300)

# Find all points above each line
above_positive = above_line(all_points=circle_3, 
                            p1=np.array([100, 100]), 
                            p2=np.array([300, 300]))  # pos sloped line
above_negative = above_line(all_points=circle_3, 
                            p1=np.array([100, 500]), 
                            p2=np.array([300, 300]))  # neg sloped line

# Find all points in each ring
ring_1 = circle_1
ring_2 = {i for i in circle_2 if i not in circle_1}
ring_3 = {i for i in circle_3 if i not in circle_2}

# Find all points in each wedge
wedge_0 = {i for i in circle_3 if (i in above_negative) and 
          (i in above_positive)}
wedge_1 = {i for i in circle_3 if (i in above_negative) and 
          (i not in above_positive)}
wedge_2 = {i for i in circle_3 if (i not in above_negative) and 
          (i not in above_positive)}
wedge_3 = {i for i in circle_3 if (i not in above_negative) and 
          (i in above_positive)}

# Take colours and convert each value to int (my data is floats, but 
# I have used ints for this example)
image = [255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]

for index, value in enumerate(image):
    image[index] = np.int64(round(abs(value)))

# Build a list where each index holds the coordinates for a particular 
# section [{section 0 cords} ... {section 11 cords}]
wedges = [wedge_0, wedge_1, wedge_2, wedge_3]
rings = [ring_1, ring_2, ring_3]
cords_in_sections = []
section_number = 0

for ring in rings:
    current_index = 0

    while current_index < len(wedges):
        points = {i for i in ring if i in wedges[current_index]}
        cords_in_sections.append(points)

        section_number += 1
        current_index += 1

# Create an 600x600 matrix of white pixels, then change pixel values in 
# each section
pixel_matrix = np.full((600, 600), 255)

# This is ugly, but seem to work better than a {cord: colour} dict 
for row, y in enumerate(pixel_matrix):
    for column, x in enumerate(y):
        if (column, row) in cords_in_sections[0]:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = image[0]
        elif (column, row) in cords_in_sections[1]:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = image[1]
        elif (column, row) in cords_in_sections[2]:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = image[2]
        elif (column, row) in cords_in_sections[3]:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = image[3]
        elif (column, row) in cords_in_sections[4]:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = image[4]
        elif (column, row) in cords_in_sections[5]:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = image[5]
        elif (column, row) in cords_in_sections[6]:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = image[6]
        elif (column, row) in cords_in_sections[7]:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = image[7]
        elif (column, row) in cords_in_sections[8]:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = image[8]
        elif (column, row) in cords_in_sections[9]:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = image[9]
        elif (column, row) in cords_in_sections[10]:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = image[10]
        elif (column, row) in cords_in_sections[11]:
            pixel_matrix[row, column] = image[11]

plt.imshow(pixel_matrix, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

This code produces the following image:

[image]

Another example from a different image array:

[image]